# Catching exceptions on the main-thread

Tags: objective-c, uikit, objective-c-runtime

First of all - this is not for production code, purely for development experiments.

I'd like to be able to catch any exception that may occur on the main-thread.

For example, I'd like to catch an exception that might occur when UIKit asynchronously calls a delegate method, i.e. if the delegate method does not exist.

I am able to do this if I for instance method-swizzle [UICollectionView layoutSubviews] to make it catch an exception, like this:

```
@implementation UICollectionView (ExceptionHandling)

-(void)swizzled_layoutSubviews {
   @try{
       [self swizzled_layoutSubviews];
   } @catch (NSException *e){
       NSLog(@"===== EXCEPTION %@ =====",e);
   }
}
....
```

But I'd really like to be able to do it more generally, so that I do not have to swizzle each and every method.

Any handy ideas?

Comment: See http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html which includes installing a handler for otherwise uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. As the article states, "If you want to test signal handling properly, you'll need to run without gdb (Run with Breakpoints off)." That's currently my problem, since I really want to use this in my development cycle, where disabling the debugger is not really a good option. Actually the handler in the article does its job on the first exception, but the next one is captured by lldb with no way of resuming.